# PL SQL - Create Procedure for New Orders

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

I'm working on a code to create a procedure to input the order quanity, product id, shipping cost, shipping method, cart type, cc number, exp date, customer id and shipping ID.

```
                  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE place_order(
                  o_qty number,
                  Product_ID int,
                  Shipping_Cost number,
                  Shipping_Method varchar,
                  Card_Type varchar,
                  CC_Number number,
                  Exp_Date varchar,
                  C_ID int,
                  S_ID int)

                  AS
                  O_ID orders.o_id%type,
                    Order_Date orders.order_date%type,
                    P_Qty products.p_qty%type,
                    O_Qty orders.o_qty%type,
                    P_Price orders.p_price%type,
                    Product_ID orders.product_id%type,
                    P_ID products.p_id%type,
                    Shipment_Date orders.shipment_date%type,
                    Delivery_Date orders.delivery_date%type,
                    Shipment_Status orders.Shipment_Status%type,
                    Order_Cost orders.Order_Cost%type,
                    Shipping_Cost orders.Shipping_Cost%type,
                    Tax orders.tax%type,
                    Total_Due orders.Total_Due%type,
                    Shipping_Method orders.Shipping_Method%type,
                    Card_Type orders.Card_Type%type,
                    CC_Number orders.cc_number%type,
                    Exp_Date orders.exp_date%type,
                    C_ID orders.C_ID%type,
                    S_ID shipping.s_id%type,
                    Shipping_days shipping.shipping_days%type,
                    Delivery_days shipping.delivery_days%type)

                  BEGIN
                      O_ID := orders_seq.NEXTVAL;
                      Order_Date := SYSDATE;
                      O_Qty := '1';
                      P_Price := 299.00;
                      Product_ID := 2200;
                      Shipment_Date := SYSDATE+Shipping_days;
                      Shipment_Status := 'Delivered';
                      Delivery_Date := SYSDATE+Delivery_days;
                      Order_Cost := (o_qty*P_Price);
                      Shipping_Cost := '20.00';
                      Tax := '1.06';
                      Total_Due := (o_qty*P_Price+Shipping_Cost)*Tax;
                      Shipping_Method := 'Express Shipping';
                      Card_Type := 'Visa';
                      CC_Number := '1111-2222-3333-4444';
                      Exp_Date := '01/17';
                      C_ID := '1000';
                      S_ID := '2';

                  IF S_ID = 1 THEN Shipping_Days := 3; END IF;
                  IF S_ID = 1 THEN Delivery_days := 5; END IF;
                  IF S_ID = 1 THEN Shipping_cost := 5; END IF;
                  IF S_ID = 2 THEN Shipping_Days := 1; END IF;
                  IF S_ID = 2 THEN Delivery_days := 2; END IF;
                  IF S_ID = 2 THEN Shipping_Cost := 20; END IF;


                  IF p_Qty = 0 Then 
                      dbms_output.put_line('Product is currently out of stock');
                  END IF;

                  IF O_Qty >= 0 Then 
                  update products SET p_qty = p_qty - o_qty where P_ID = 2200;    
                  END IF;

                  Insert into Orders(O_ID,Order_Date,o_Qty,P_Price,Product_ID,Shipment_Date,Delivery_Date,Shipment_Status,Order_Cost,Shipping_Cost,Tax,Total_Due,Shipping_Method,Card_Type,CC_Number,Exp_Date,C_ID,S_ID)
                  Values(O_ID,Order_Date,o_Qty,P_Price,Product_ID,SYSDATE+Shipping_days,SYSDATE+Delivery_days,Shipment_Status,Order_Cost,Shipping_Cost,Tax,(o_qty*P_Price+Shipping_Cost)*Tax,Shipping_Method,Card_Type,CC_Number,Exp_Date,C_ID,S_ID);
                  COMMIT;   
                      dbms_output.put_line('Order ID: ' || O_ID);
                      dbms_output.put_line('Order placed on ' || order_date);
                      dbms_output.put_line('Expected Shipping Date: ' || (order_date + Shipping_days ));
                    dbms_output.put_line('Expected Delivery Date: ' || (order_date + Delivery_days ));
                    dbms_output.put_line ('Total Order Cost: ' || Total_Due );

                  END;
```

When I try to create the program it shows the below errors
Errors for PROCEDURE PLACE_ORDER:

LINE/COL

ERROR

13/13  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the f ollowing: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
34/43  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the f ollowing: := ( , not null range default external character

Comment: You're closing out your "AS" section with a bracket ")" - that should be a ;

Comment: Oh, and all your commas in that declaration section should be ; too

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Ahhh simple error. Thanks Much. I have changed the ',' to ';' and receive the below errors:                                                                               Errors for PROCEDURE PLACE_ORDER: 


LINE/COL 

ERROR 

0/0  PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated  
1/1  PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Comment: I'd suggest you look for duplicate fields in your RECORD,TABLE or argument lists

Comment: In which section the AS or Begin? I do not see any duplicates between these

Comment: A really crazy idea might be for you to read your textbook instead of trying to fake it, it's pretty obvious that you don't have the first idea what you're actually doing here. For eg, you are declaring variables with the same name as some of your parameters. I wonder what happens when you do that?

Comment: I created an anonymous pl sql procedure that works fine and prints the order data. However, I'm trying to create this as a stored procedure. Which is my first time doing so.

Comment: Yes, it's your first time, that's exactly why it's important to read the material.

Comment: Understood. I appreciate you responding on this. Thanks